# Difficulties with PHPMailer and SES

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm moving a site from a traditional hosting provider to Amazon. I can't seem to get the mailer to work.

I did get a verified email address with SES.

I see sendmail is running.

I see lots of posting with people struggling with this as well. My code is below.

I'm getting a HTTP 500 Server error when I look at the debugger windows.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
try{
$body = "Hello, \n This is just a test mail";
$mail->Host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; // SMTP server of Amazon SES
$mail->Port = 587; // SMTP port of the Amazon SES
$mail->Username = "xxxxxxxx"; // SMTP username (Amazon SES Credentials)
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx"; // SMTP password (Amazon SES Credentials)
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // 1 to enables SMTP debug (for testing), 0 to disable debug (for production)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // tls required for Amazon SES
$mail->SetFrom('x@x.com', 'x');
$mail->AddReplyTo('x@x.com', 'x');
$mail->AddAddress('x@x.com, 'x');
$mail->Subject = 'New Subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Send();
} 
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```